# Creating an Oracle trigger on table insert

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have 2 tables, one called EMPLOYEE, and the second called CURRENT_EMPLOYYE in SQL Developer.

table EMPLOYEE has three fields:
ID(type:number, PK),FNAME(type:varchar2 50), DATE (type:date)

table CURRENT_EMPLOYYE has three fields:
ID(type:number, PK),FNAME(type:varchar2 50), DATE (type:date)

What i'm trying to do is create a trigger on table EMPLOYEE, so that when a record is inserted in this table,it's then inserted in the table CURRENT_EMPLOYYE.

Any help on how to do so?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=oracle+insert+trigger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking what you seem to want is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER EMPLOYEE_AI
  AFTER INSERT ON EMPLOYEE
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO CURRENT_EMPLOYEE
    (ID, FNAME, DATE)
  VALUES
    (:NEW.ID, :NEW.FNAME, :NEW.DATE);
END EMPLOYEE_AI;
```

A better choice would be to have a 'STATUS' field on EMPLOYEE indicating the status of the employee (e.g. 'C' = current, 'T' = terminated, 'X' = terminated with extreme prejudice :-) and then just have CURRENT_EMPLOYEE be a view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW CURRENT_EMPLOYEE AS
  SELECT *
    FROM EMPLOYEE
    WHERE STATUS = 'C'
```

This way you wouldn't have the problem of having the employee data duplicated on multiple tables.

Best of luck.

Comment: DEAR when i try to create the script in the sql developer editor, i get a pop up to enter binds for NEW. What's this about?

Comment: I've never used SQL Developer so I can't help you out there. That sounds like a separate question - I suggest you post it.

Comment: Just to reinforce Bob Jarvis's comment about the design.  Your proposed two-table design is fundamentally flawed and violates the rules of data normalization, upon which the entire theory of relational database design is built. Rather than build the trigger, you'd (and your employer) would be far, FAR better off with a single table that has a status column.